# any example for creating an iOS custom button?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I would like to create a custom button, which have a custom background image, icon and a label.
It looks very similar like the Twitter button i found:

[image]

Any good suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import quartz

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

then to create button like your twitter button simply write this code:

```
UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 50);
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
yourButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
yourButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:57.0/255.0 green:178.0/255.0 blue:235.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

//if you want to set image as background
//[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal] 

[yourButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton setTitle:@"Twitter" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter_icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Is it possible to set custom frame for the twitter_icon ?

Comment: [yourButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 0, 4, 40)];
works!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the button type to "custom" in interface builder. Then you can set the background image, icon, text, and colors to whatever you prefer.

To get rounded corners, you'll have to add some code:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // Change to the value you desire.
button.clipsToBounds = YES;
```